# Why I installed Xubuntu Desktop after Installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, compiz, xubuntu, xfce

I needed to solve all these problems :

1. I don't like the Unity interface
2. Ubuntu 13.10 has iBus language input method problem eg. Chinese
3. If you install Xubuntu distro, you have to install many apps eg. libreoffice by yourself
4. To help those gets a blank screen after installing Ubuntu (its due to unsupported video card hardware) or those who tried to remove unity but got a blank screen after rebooting.

Comment: Errr.. You could always ask the question, and then answer it separately...

Comment: Or just simply install Xubutnu.

Answer (score 2):

(Moving OP's own answer to an Answer:)

so after installing Ubuntu 13.10 and booting up,   I did the following :

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> (even if you got blank screen or just see the Ubuntu wallpaper) and enter :

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

note: while in ccsm, disable the unity plugin
Then I enter :

```
sudo apt-get upate && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and login, then enter :

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo Xorg -configure
sudo reboot
```

Your computer  should now start up with Xubuntu Xfce 4 desktop and having all your Ubuntu apps and data intact eg. firefox or chrome browser history, cookies.

Go to Settings Manager and do configurations eg. session and startup

This posting will be of interest to those who want Ubuntu but whose computer hardware does not support Unity desktop or those who do not like to use the Unity desktop.

Important note :  your location affects your download of Ubuntu software, so to be safe, choose a location where you know the servers (will with high probability) have the complete software.  Your location is specified when you select Time and Date.  Do not trust mirror sites outside the US.

Comment: Very good, but you could improve some formatting, and use keyboard `<kbd></kbd>` markdown... ;-)

Comment: @wilf I'm perfectionist, but up to a limit. :)